# infinite scroll in React + Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, infinite-scroll

I'm using Meteor with React. I cannot implement infinite scrolling. I have tried different npm and Meteor packages and it's still not working. "createContainer" subscribes to the whole dataset of "links", which is then rendered in the app. How can subscribe to just 9 entries and load more whenever a user is at the end of the page? 
I have spent the whole day on it, please help me!

```
class DealsList extends Component {


    renderList() {
        return this.props.links.map(link => {
        const url = `/travels/${link._id}`;

        return (
            <div className="col-md-4" key={link._id}>
            <Link  to={url} id={link._id}>
                <div className="thumbnail">

                <div className="imageProp">
                    <div className="caption readMore">SHOW DEAL <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
                    <img src={link.image} alt="Just another travel deal" />
                </div>

                <div className="caption">
                    <h4>{link.title}</h4>
                    {/*<p className="card-description"><strong>Bootstrap Thumbnail</strong> Customization Example. Here are customized <strong>bootstrap cards</strong>. We just apply some box shadow and remove border radius.</p>
                    <p><a href="#" className="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></p>*/}
                </div>

                </div>
            </Link>
            </div>

        );
        });
    }


    render() {

        return (
          <div> 
          <FirstCarousel />
          <div className="container-fluid containerPadding cards-row">
              <div className="row">

              <div className="col-lg-12">
                  <div className="row grid">
                      {this.renderList()}
                  </div>
              </div>

              </div>

          </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}



export default createContainer(() => {

Meteor.subscribe('links');

return { links: Links.find({}).fetch() };
}, DealsList);
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to not to go for infinite scroll, cause every template Instance or component will be subscribed to some collection, with every scroll fetch, subscription s will keep on increasing and may cause network jam.

Comment: what can you offer then?

Comment: Pagination was always a good option

Answer (score 0):

There's a good [chapter about pagination and infinite scroll in the Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#pagination), you should check it out. In essence, what you need to do, is give your `lists` publication a parameter to specify the number of items that will be fetched, like so:

```
Meteor.publish('links', (limit) => {
  const options = {
    sort: {time: -1}, // Or some other relevant sorting
    limit
  };
  return Links.find({}, options);
};
```

Now your the **parent** component that contains your `DealsList`, you need to do two things: 1. Hold a state variable for the `limit`, with some appropriate initial value, that is passed down to your `DealsList`. 2. Increase this limit by some amount when the user reaches the bottom of the page. You can find multiple guides on how to do that if you search, for example you can look at [this](http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/08/detect-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of.html#.WTVbKGjyiUk).

Once those are done, you can simply use the limit parameter in the subscription like this:

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  Meteor.subscribe('links', props.limit);
  return { links: Links.find({}).fetch() };
}, DealsList);
```